# SQL update with regular expressions

Tags: sql, regex

I have a rather complex issue with an SQL query and was wondering if it is possible.

```
SELECT Orders.ShipName
FROM Orders
WHERE (((Orders.ShipName) Like "[[]*[]]"))
ORDER BY Orders.ShipName;
```

this finds all results that have a containing [] i.e. [test]

however i wish to remove the [] from the string and then update. Unfortunately i am constrained to SQL only so i am not very experienced with this.

I haven't a clue where to start. Can anyone give any tips help regarding this?

Comment: @JorgeCampos this was using the ms access sample database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just removing those characters

```
update orders
set shipname = replace(replace(shipname, '[',''),']','')
```

Comment: It worked for the question that i asked so thankyou very much